# Android Bluetooth: Get UUIDs of discovered devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

As I'm currently working on a little bluetooth library for Android, I'm trying to get all the service uuids of the devices I discovered in my surrounding.

When my broadcast receiver gets the `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND` intent, I'm extracting the device and call:

```
device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
```

This will result `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID` intents for each device found and I'm handling them with the same receiver:

```
BluetoothDevice d = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
Parcelable[] uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);

if(uuidExtra ==  null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "UUID = null");
}

if(d != null && uuidExtra != null)
    Log.d(TAG, d.getName() + ": " + uuidExtra.toString());
```

The thing is, that `uuidExtra` is always `null`.

How can i get all the UUIDs of the surrounding devices?

EDIT:

Im working on a Nexus 7. I tried code i found on the internet and this also gives me a NullPointerException: http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.de/2012/05/android-example-bluetooth-discover-and.html

Thank you.

Comment: Im facing the exact situation! did you find any solution ? can you please help me.

Answer (score 16):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_UUID) on this states...

> Always contains the extra field `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID`

However, just like you, I have found this not to be true.

If you call `fetchUuidsWithSdp()` while device discovery is still taking place `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID` can be null.

You should wait until you receive `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` before you make any calls to `fetchUuidsWithSdp()`.

Comment: I get the same problem, even if i wait for device discovery to finish before calling `fetchUuidsWithSdp()`.

Comment: This works for me in some cases. When discovering devices from my Samsung Galaxy Nexus 2, I can only receive the services on my HTC One (M7), not from my MacBook Pro (then the result is null).

Comment: EDIT: it seems completely random if `fetchUuidsWithSdp()` works or not, no matter at which point in the process I call it.

Comment: This works like charm. For the scenarios where we feel the behavior as random, see my answer below.

Comment: ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED  is never called even if I added `filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);`

Answer (score 12):

> **NOTE:** This solution applies to `CLASSIC` bluetooth and not `BLE`. For `BLE` check how to send
>   manufacturer specific Data in advertiser on the peripheral side

The problem with fetching Uuids is that you have only one bluetooth adapter, and we cannot have parallel api calls which uses adapter for its purpose.

As Eddie pointed out, wait for `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` and then call `fetchUuidsWithSdp()`.

Still this cannot guarantee uuids to be fetched for all devices. In addition to this one must wait for each subsequent call to `fetchuuidsWithSdp()`  to complete, and then give a call to this method for another device.

See the code below --

```
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            mDeviceList.add(device);
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            // discovery has finished, give a call to fetchUuidsWithSdp on first device in list.
            if (!mDeviceList.isEmpty()) {
                BluetoothDevice device = mDeviceList.remove(0);
                boolean result = device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
            }
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)) {
            // This is when we can be assured that fetchUuidsWithSdp has completed.
            // So get the uuids and call fetchUuidsWithSdp on another device in list

            BluetoothDevice deviceExtra = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Parcelable[] uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
            System.out.println("DeviceExtra address - " + deviceExtra.getAddress());
            if (uuidExtra != null) {
                for (Parcelable p : uuidExtra) {
                    System.out.println("uuidExtra - " + p);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("uuidExtra is still null");
            }
            if (!mDeviceList.isEmpty()) {
                BluetoothDevice device = mDeviceList.remove(0);
                boolean result = device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **UPDATE:** Latest android versions (mm & above) would result in triggering a pairing process with each device

Comment: Interesting I still get null though :(

Comment: Make sure to register the intents.

Comment: Which action triggers the pairing process? FetchUuidWithSdp()? If so I assume that is because a connection needs to be established? If that is true, why is the pairing process only triggered in MM and up?

Comment: Yes. The reason is that security is being tightened going forward in newer versions of Android (mostly after MM). Plus a special care is being given to drop BT connection if there is no active data transfer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good example of how to get UUIDs of service characteristics from a service that I did for getting heart rate devices:

```
private class HeartRateBluetoothGattCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {         
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            logMessage("CONNECTED TO " + gatt.getDevice().getName(), false, false);
            gatt.discoverServices();    
        } else if(newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            logMessage("DISCONNECTED FROM " + gatt.getDevice().getName(), false, false);
            if(mIsTrackingHeartRate)
                handleHeartRateDeviceDisconnection(gatt);
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            logMessage("DISCOVERING SERVICES FOR " + gatt.getDevice().getName(), false, false);

            if(mDesiredHeartRateDevice != null && 
                    gatt.getDevice().getAddress().equals(mDesiredHeartRateDevice.getBLEDeviceAddress())) {

                if(subscribeToHeartRateGattServices(gatt)) {

                    mIsTrackingHeartRate = true;
                    setDeviceScanned(getDiscoveredBLEDevice(gatt.getDevice().getAddress()), DiscoveredBLEDevice.CONNECTED);
                    broadcastHeartRateDeviceConnected(gatt.getDevice());

                } else
                    broadcastHeartRateDeviceFailedConnection(gatt.getDevice());

            } else {
                parseGattServices(gatt);
                disconnectGatt(getDiscoveredBLEDevice(gatt.getDevice().getAddress()));
            }
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if(characteristic.getUuid().equals(UUID.fromString(HEART_RATE_VALUE_CHAR_READ_ID))) {
            int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
            int format = -1;

            if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) 
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            else 
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;

            Integer heartRateValue = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
            if(heartRateValue != null)
                broadcastHeartRateValue(heartRateValue);
            else
                Log.w(SERVICE_NAME, "UNABLE TO FORMAT HEART RATE DATA");
        }
    };

};

private void parseGattServices(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
    boolean isHeartRate = false;
    for(BluetoothGattService blueToothGattService : gatt.getServices()) {
        logMessage("GATT SERVICE: " + blueToothGattService.getUuid().toString(), false, false);
        if(blueToothGattService.getUuid().toString().contains(HEART_RATE_DEVICE_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC_PREFIX))
            isHeartRate = true;
    }   

    if(isHeartRate) {
        setDeviceScanned(getDiscoveredBLEDevice(gatt.getDevice().getAddress()), DiscoveredBLEDevice.IS_HEART_RATE);
        broadcastHeartRateDeviceFound(getDiscoveredBLEDevice(gatt.getDevice().getAddress()));
    } else 
        setDeviceScanned(getDiscoveredBLEDevice(gatt.getDevice().getAddress()), DiscoveredBLEDevice.NOT_HEART_RATE);
}

private void handleHeartRateDeviceDisconnection(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
    broadcastHeartRateDeviceDisconnected(gatt.getDevice());
    gatt.close();

    clearoutHeartRateData();
    scanForHeartRateDevices();
}

private void disconnectGatt(DiscoveredBLEDevice device) {
    logMessage("CLOSING GATT FOR " + device.getBLEDeviceName(), false, false);
    device.getBlueToothGatt().close();
    device.setBlueToothGatt(null);
    mInDiscoveryMode = false;
}

private boolean subscribeToHeartRateGattServices(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
    for(BluetoothGattService blueToothGattService : gatt.getServices()) {
        if(blueToothGattService.getUuid().toString().contains(HEART_RATE_DEVICE_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC_PREFIX)) {
            mHeartRateGattService = blueToothGattService;

            for(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : mHeartRateGattService.getCharacteristics()) {
                logMessage("CHARACTERISTIC UUID = " + characteristic.getUuid().toString(), false, false);

                for(BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor :characteristic.getDescriptors()) {
                    logMessage("DESCRIPTOR UUID = " + descriptor.getUuid().toString(), false, false);
                }

                if(characteristic.getUuid().equals(UUID.fromString(HEART_RATE_VALUE_CHAR_READ_ID))) {
                    gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
                    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(HEART_RATE_VALUE_CHAR_DESC_ID));
                    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                    return gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                }
            }

            break; //break out of master for-loop
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I believe the question is geared for Bluetooth Classic, not Bluetooth LE... as is the case with yours mentioning "services," "characteristics," "gatt," and heart-rate devices.

Answer (score 3):

**device.getUuids()** use this to get all the uuid of that paired device in the form of ParcelUuid; Example code below:-

```
private void get_uuid_from_paired_devices(){
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        for (BluetoothDevice device: pairedDevices){

            for (ParcelUuid uuid: device.getUuids()){
                String uuid_string = uuid.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "uuid : "+uuid_string);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need to be paired with the device in order to receive the uuids.
At least, this is what happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me to fetch the records from the remote device

```
-0-
registerReceiver(..,
                new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID));
```

-1-
device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();

-2-from within the broadcase receiver

```
   if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)) {
                        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                        Parcelable[] uuids = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
                        for (Parcelable ep : uuids) {
                            Utilities.print("UUID records : "+ ep.toString());
                        }
                    }
```

You can also fetch the offline cached UUID records with

```
 BluetoothDevice.getUuids();
```

Comment: I tried `getUuids()` with three different BLE devices and all returned a null array.

Comment: The getUuids() is for classic only as I understand it. Its completely different for BTLE!

Comment: This helped me figure it out. I had to use 'GetParcelableArrayExtra' instead of 'GetParcelableExtra'. The fact that that's not mentioned in any of the official documentation I looked at is frustrating.