# Connecting to a custom device via Bluetooth when its SDK is unavailable

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am building an Android app in which I need to connect to an custom device over classic Bluetooth (preferably). My problem is SDK for that device is not created to facilitate the connection. Now I am stuck onto the part where I need to create a Socket which will be opened by the custom device which is acting as a server and other Android devices will act as clients and connect to it. 
I am stuck at the part where we need to have identical UUIDs at both client and server for the socket connection to work. I am following the BleutoothChatApp as reference for this but I cannot always make sure that both my app and custom device will have identical UUIDs. Because I may or may not be able to hard code the UUID in custom device.
What can I do in such case.?
Also when I try to use BLE and search for services, I discover only one service which has no description or anything. 
What can I do in such cases. What will be the best approach to create a connection to that device.?

Comment: This question and `ArunKumar`'s answer would help you
[Get UUIDs of discovered devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812326/android-bluetooth-get-uuids-of-discovered-devices)

Comment: But is there any other way? Because when I use the references from above answer and check for UUIDs of discovered devices, I get multiple UUIDs for same device. What can I do in such case.?

Answer (score 2):

You get multiple UUIDs for the same device because the devices offer multiple services. [Base UUID for Bluetooth](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery) is "00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB".

If you find this UUID in a device, it means it supports Bluetooth Service. Use the UUID for connecting to the device.